# Function taking another function of arbitrary arity as argument

Tags: scala, shapeless, arity

I have a series of functions that accept a function as an argument (`func`), and the only difference in them is that `func` accepts different numbers of parameters.

```
  def tryGet[T,A](func: (A) => T)
  def tryGet[T,A,B](func: (A,B) => T)
  ...       [T,A,B,C...]
```

Is there a way to make a function accept a function with any length argument list?

I tried using variable length argument lists, eg `func:(A*)` but had trouble passing any functions in as it now requires a `Seq[A]`.

Comment: If you do not know the number and type of the arguments of the function. How do you expect to call / use it?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I had expected to be able to call like so: `func()`.  For example if I wanted to pass in the function `def getSomething(int:Int) = Future.successful(int)`, by calling tryGet like so `tryGet( (int:Int) => getSomething(int) )` I was using `func() map { ... handle exceptions and return an Option instead}`.   The wider question i'm trying to solve is can I wrap a load of API calls that throw exceptions, so that they throw Options instead in the case of NoSuchElementExceptions.

Comment: Eg `tryGet` shouldn't know or care what the function is, it only knows that if `func` throws some specific exceptions it should return `None`, and if it doesn't then it should return `Some(T)`

Comment: How do you expect `func()` to compile? If it may take any number of arguments? You do not really want to pass any kind of function. But rather any kind o block that results on `Future[T]` and call something over it. Something like `def tryGet[T](block: => Future[T]): Future[Option[T]] = block.recoverWith(...)`.

Comment: Other alternative would be to just receive a function `A => T` where **A** is any kind of **product**. Thus, if you need two arguments, you pass them as a tuple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use `shapeless.ops.function.FnToProduct`

```
def tryGet[F: FnToProduct](func: F) = ???

val f1: Int => String = ???
val f2: (Int, Int) => String = ???
val f3: (Int, Int, Int) => String = ???

tryGet(f1)
tryGet(f2)
tryGet(f3)
```

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#facilities-for-abstracting-over-arity

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use scala.util.Try? Or simply pass the argument to tryGet not as a block but as a by-name parameter of type T?

Comment: Thanks but I don't know how to do that, an example would be great!

Comment: `Try(unaryFunc(a))
Try(binaryFunc(a, b)).toOption`

or, if you wish to do it all manually,

`def tryGet[T](func: => T) = try { Some(func) } catch { case ex: Exception => None }`